# IDA Pro Dereference Pointer from a Register and a Constant offset

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, ida

I have a piece of assembly code like the following:

```
mov eax [edi + 24h]
```

Is there a quick way in IDA Pro to resolve that is a value without having to navigate to the address, figure out what the value is, and add 24h to it?  A command line shortcut would be great.

Comment: How should IDA know this? In some cases it knows, but most often it will not. It's a runtime calculated address, so either you must deduce it from what is before this instruction, or you musst look with a debugger.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it would be obvious that I had the debugger attached and in the proper location.

Comment: You can also just double-click the operand to follow the address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're debugging, the following trick works:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> ("User-defined offset")
2. Enter "`edi`" in the "Base address" field.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You'll get something like:

```
mov eax, [edi + (target_address - edi_value)]
```

This works because during debugging the IDC interpreter recognizes register names and evaluates them. And most numerical input fields in IDA accept IDC expressions.